# i can't display/access images from the mysql database using php

Tags: php, html, sql

I was able to design a code to upload image and other data to the database and also display some of those data. Everything works but the image doesn't display and the messages too don't come up when the action is completed or not. How can I display/access the stored images from mysql database? Here is the complete code.
below is the php code and the html code which i designed
<?php
//for image upload

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message']="";


$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','auction');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$item_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['item_name']);
$item_description = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['item_description']);
$item_image_path = $mysqli-
>real_escape_string('Images/item_img/'.$_FILES['item_image']['name']);

//make sure file is of image type
if (preg_match("!image!", $_FILES['item_image']['type'])) {
    if (copy($_FILES['item_image']['tmp_name'], $item_image_path)) {
        $_SESSION['item_name'] = $item_name;
        $_SESSION['item_description'] = $item_description;  
        $_SESSION['item_image'] = $item_image_path;
        $sql = "INSERT INTO items (item_name, item_image_path, 
item_description)
                VALUES('$item_name', 
 '$item_image_path','$item_description')";
        if ($mysqli->query($sql) == true) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "Item Upload Successful!";
        } else {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "file upload failed";
        }
        
    }
    else{
        $_SESSION['message'] = "file copying failed";
}
    }
     else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = "please upload gif, jpg, png";
}

}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload item</title>
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.main.css">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <?php
                $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','auction');
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM items ";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                
                    echo "<img 
src='Images\item_img/".$row['item_image']."'>";
                    echo "<p>".$row['item_name']."</p>";
                    
                }
            ?>
        </div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" 
action="auction_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h1><? = $_SESSION['message'];?></h1>
            <div class=" form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <INPUT type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name" 
required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Image:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <INPUT type="file" class="form-control" name="item_image" 
accept="image/*" required/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Item Description:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="item_description" required>
</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="form-group"> 
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8"> 
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
name="upload">Upload</button>
  </div> 
</div> 
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, so what is on line 10 and 13 of `C:\xampp2\htdocs\trail\auction_upload.php`?

Comment: You have to forgot to declare image variable or you are using another variable name

Comment: here is the whole source code.

Comment: sorry i'm finding it difficult to include the code here at stackoverflow. I have decided to include the link for the screenshoots instead.

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/6lxuxzkj9/

Comment: https://s2.postimg.org/e1x4js88p/Screenshot_66.png

Comment: Codes as images are no use. No one can copy text out of it to do any debugging. Please edit your question and add the code to that.

Comment: i figured it out. I decided to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have figured it out. i decided to use

```
 echo "<img src='$row[item_image]'>";
```

instead of the previous

```
echo "<img src='Images\item_img/".$row['item_image']."'>";
```